# a GUI on top of EGL?

Tags: c++, user-interface, egl

looks like EGL will be the next most popular standard for interfacing a "GUI Window" to the graphical server, my question is: there is a GUI framework, maybe in C++, that is able to create widgets and a nice GUI on top of EGL ?

I'm excluding GTK, QT, Wx, for different reasons and they also don't fit what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made an incorrect assumption about what EGL is, EGL is merely a standard interface to frameubber configurations, native buffers such as pixmaps, windows and rendering contexts, infact very similar to what WGL and GLX provides, and is to some extent modeled to mirror these API's. In early days it was meant as an interface on mobile devices but nowdays we are seeing more and more implementations arriving on desktop, even supporting the full OpenGL profile rather than just OpenGL ES.

So this means any GUI framework that uses any of the client API's EGL supports would be applicable to this question, there are many of them but here's a few examples of such libraries [GWEN](https://github.com/garrynewman/GWEN), [GLAM](http://glam.sourceforge.net/), [libRocket](http://librocket.com/)